# Unable to read content using their column headers making use of openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm trying to read the content of an excel file using it's column headers making use of ***openpyxl*** library but I can't find any idea to do so.

This is usually what I do to read the items using column index(working one).

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('company_info.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

for i in range(1, ws.max_row + 1):
    if ws.cell(row=i,column=1).value==None:break
    print(ws.cell(row=i,column=1).value,ws.cell(row=i,column=2).value,ws.cell(row=i,column=3).value)
```

The content in excel are like:

[image]

> ***How can I read the companies or countries using their column headers?***

Note: I'm only after any solution related to ***openpyxl***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *openpyxl* library seems to have a lot of little hidden gems.  Hopefully, this is what you needed.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook('company_info.xlsx', data_only=True)
sheet = book.active
company_names = sheet['A']
company_id = sheet['B']
country = sheet['C']

for company in company_names:
  if company.value != 'Company':
    print(company.value)
    # output
    Amigo Foods
    Atlantic Shrimpers Limited
    Amawar Hiwam Co.
    Austral Fishers Pyt Ltd
    Alpha Group - Headquarters

for country in company_location:
  if country.value != 'Country':
    print(country.value)
    # output
    Nepal
    Nigeria
    Myanmar
    Australia
    Kenya

 for id in company_id:
   if id.value != 'ID':
     print (id.value)
     # output
     ED5634
     PN7809
     QZ3871
     TR1089
     UY3090

 max_column = sheet.max_column
 max_row = sheet.max_row

 for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=max_row, min_col=1, 
   max_col=max_column, values_only=True):
   print (row)
   # output
   ('Amigo Foods', 'ED5634', 'Nepal')
   ('Atlantic Shrimpers Limited', 'PN7809', 'Nigeria')
   ('Amawar Hiwam Co.', 'QZ3871', 'Myanmar')
   ('Austral Fishers Pyt Ltd', 'TR1089', 'Australia')
   ('Alpha Group - Headquarters', 'UY3090', 'Kenya')


 for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=max_row, min_col=1,
   max_col=max_column, values_only=True):
   company_name = row[0]
   company_id = row[1]
   company_location = row[2]
   if 'Amawar' in company_name:
     print (row)
     # output
     ('Amawar Hiwam Co.', 'QZ3871', 'Myanmar')
```

Comment: No damn way!!!! Yes, this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot @Life is complex.

Comment: You're welcome.   This library has a lot of flexibility, but its documentation needs some updating.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem, but you can indeed retrieve a column by header letter:

```py
wb = load_workbook('company_info.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

companies = ws['A']  # A generator of cells
for company in companies:
    print(company.value)
```

Comment: Which part of my question is unclear to you? To be clearer - I would like to read values from that excel file using it's headers the way we read values from a csv file using `DictReader`. Your above approach doesn't make any sense. Where did you find this `worksheet`? Moreover, it `company_cell` will definitely throw `name error`.

Comment: Updated my example. I don't think you can do what you wish with `openpyxl`, it's more a job for [`pandas.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)